# Avoid lazyloader attribute

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, lazy-loading, c#-2.0

I´ve been looking for how avoid return a list without the attribute **lazyLoader**, I want to continue using the lazyLoader but I don´t want return the attribute when I return the whole list of my entity from my controller

I´m working with .NET core.

```
[
  {
    "lazyLoader": {},
    "id": "id1"
    "name": "name"
  },
  {
    "lazyLoader": {},
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name2"
  }
]
```

Comment: You could configure the serializer to use an opt-in strategy and tack serializer attributes onto entity properties.

Comment: Or just decorate properties you want to suppress with JsonIgnoreAttribute https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm

Comment: Jsonignore it,s working when you hava a real attribute in a class but lazyloader is added from the framework

Comment: I'll try de serializer maybe can be a solution.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold for help me to find the solution. The serializer it´s the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a select of you collection only retrieving the rest of the data.
That way your objects will not have the Navigation property at all.

```
db.YourCollection.Where(your condition)Select(x => new { id = x.id , name = x.name } );
```

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework, if you have an object where one or more of its properties use lazy loading, check its runtime type name using GetType().Name. For an object of a **Car** class, for example, you will notice that the runtime type is actually something called **CarProxy**, which is a temporary in-memory type created by Entity Framework using **reflection**. This "fake" proxy class's base type is **Car**, and has all the original **Car** properties, but includes an extra one called *LazyLoader* for properties that may need it.

If you do further checking on this "fake" **CarProxy** type, you will also see that **Assembly.IsDynamic = true**, which is indicative that the class was created dynamically using reflection (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.isdynamic?view=netframework-4.8)):

```
var TheCar = DBContext.Cars.Find(1);
Console.WriteLine(TheCar.GetType().Assembly.IsDynamic.ToString()); //will echo "true"
```

Luckily, **Newtonsoft.Json** has an override on the **JsonConvert.SerializeObject()** method that allows us to provide a base type, so that the resulting JSON doesn't contain properties that don't exist in that type. So, to eliminate the *LazyLoader* property, just provide the object's BaseType as the type parameter:

```
var TheCar = DBContext.Cars.Find(1);
var TheJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TheCar, TheCar.GetType().BaseType);
```

To make sure you don't get any circular reference loops when serializing (a very high probability when using lazy loading), call the serializer with the following setting:

```
var TheCar = DBContext.Cars.Find(1);
var Settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
var TheJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TheCar, TheCar.GetType().BaseType, Settings);
```

**Note: This may only work on the first level deep when the serializer travels through the object. If there are yet more lazy-loading child properties of the object you provide to the serializer, the "LazyLoader" property may appear again. I haven't tested it so I can't say for sure.**

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but add

```
public boolean ShouldSerializeLazyLoader() { return false; }
```

to all the classes down the tree of the ones you want to serialize, and you will get a lazyloader free JSON.

Ref.: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm

Answer (score 1):

The checked answer for this question is just working for the root object, if we have many nested lazyloaded objects, this solution will not work.
Although the answer of @[Marcello-Barbiani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56384230/1334979) is correct but it is not a good way to add this function to all entities we have.

The best way is create a new ContractResolver derived from DefaultContractResolver and check if property is Lazyloader then skip it as below:

```
 public class NonLazyloaderContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
 {
        public new static readonly NonLazyloaderContractResolver Instance = new NonLazyloaderContractResolver();

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

            if (property.PropertyName == "LazyLoader")
            {
                property.ShouldSerialize = i => false;                    
            }

            return property;
        }
}
```

after that adding above class pass it through JsonSerializerSettings while serializing the object:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newProduct, new JsonSerializerSettings() {
                ContractResolver = new NonLazyloaderContractResolver(),
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore });
```

and finally if you are using asp.net core or asp.net core webapi add this contract as default contractresolver in startup.cs file:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new NonLazyloaderContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```